# Trying to dynamically render JSX tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm creating a `<Text />` component so I can easily control how Text is used in my app. I want to be able to choose a tag for the `<Text />` component, depending on what it is (`<p>` for body text, `<h1>` for a title, for example).

However, I'm stuck on the first step. When I try to use a function to return a tag, I get the following error:

`Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)`

Here's my component:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export class Text extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  getMarkup() {
    return 'h1'
  }

  render() {
    const CustomTag = this.getMarkup()
    return (<CustomTag>Hello</CustomTag>)
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects

Comment: Is this working in a react app without typescript? Have you checked that once?

Comment: can you add sandbox with replication of error?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're going to treat the tags as string, you could use the `React.createElement`. Inside the `render`, write as follow:

```
const element = React.createElement(this.getMarkup(), {}, 'Hello');
return <>{element}</>;
```

Basically, `createElement` expects the type of the element as string, so you can pass the `'h1'` without having TypeScript bothering you.
Moreover, you can see that I pass an empty array as second argument: there you could pass any props like `style`, `onClick`, ... Usually, in this case, you would write as follow:

```
const element = React.createElement(this.getMarkup(), {{...this.props}}, 'Hello');
```

But of course, you would need to add the proper types in the `Text` props using the `React.HTMLProps<T>`.. Something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component<React.HTMLProps<HTMLHeadingElement | HTMLParagraphElement>, IState> {`
```

Where in this case I consider just the `h` and `p` elements.

**EDIT:** If you are gonna combine the `HTMLProps` with props of your own, like `IProps`, then you are going to write `IProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLHeadingElement | HTMLParagraphElement>`.

At this point, inside `this.props` you will have the (`p`|`h`) props AND the props defined inside the `IProps`.

Then, at this point, since `p` and `h` element shouldn't take the props coming from `IProps`, you should rewrite the `createElement` as follow:

```
// Assuming you have this IProps
interface IProps {
  tag: string;
  myProp: number;
}

// Inside render
const { tag, myProp, ...otherProps } = {...this.props};
const element = React.createElement(this.getMarkup(), otherProps, 'Hello');
return <>{element}</>;
```

Comment: Hey @Jolly how do you add IProps given `<React.HTMLProps<HTMLHeadingElement | HTMLParagraphElement>`?

Comment: What is `IProps`? The base props your `App`? You can just use the `&` operator to "merge" TypeScript interfaces. If  you write `IProps & React.HTMLProps<HTMLHeadingElement | HTMLParagraphElement>`, your props will expect whatever is inside the the `IProps` and the base props of a `h` or `p` element. Then, be aware that when passing the props to `createElement` you may need to remove the props coming from `IProps`.. I'll edit the answer with this new piece of information